# CMake source filename transformation when compiling in wine

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, wine, toolchain

I'm writing a CMake toolchain file for compiling on Linux with MSVC compiler in wine:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "cl")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "cl")
```

The `~/bin/cl` file:

```
wine cmd /c Z:/home/velkan/bin/cl.bat "$@"
```

The `~/bin/cl.bat` file:

```
call Z:\home\velkan\bin\vcvars32.bat
cl %*
```

The `~/bin/vcvars32.bat` file:

```
@echo off
Set INCLUDE=C:\vc\include;C:\sdk\Include;C:\kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt;%INCLUDE%
Set LIB=C:\vc\lib;C:\sdk\Lib;C:\kits\10\Lib\10.0.10586.0\ucrt\x86;%LIB%
```

Copied all needed stuff into the wine dir, so the compiler works.

But when I run cmake, it passes Unix-style paths like `/home/velkan/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c` to the compiler. Is there any CMake workaround for the toolchain definition that can seamlessly convert them to something like `Z:/home/velkan/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c`?

Comment: CMake determines type of path delimiter by *generator*, toolchain doesn't affect on this low-level things. You need to use generator for Windows, like "NMake Makefiles" for use windows paths. Alternatively, your compiler script may convert these paths before use them.

Comment: I went with the compiler script. There are lots of other problems too, so I'm not sure what will be the final solution.

Comment: have you tried running a windows version of cmake under wine as well?

Comment: @Joe, wanted as little windows as possible.

Comment: @Velkan sure, but it would see Windows style paths within wine.